# What to do, if voting-based Q&A does not work at all?

Tags: discussion

As it has often stated, the standard approach to an incorrect, but highly voted or even accepted, answer is to add a correct answer and comment/vote down and wait for the correct answer to raise and the incorrect to lower… eventually.

The problem with the question [“Java: Clear the console”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979383/2711488), is, that the wrong answer, `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");` has been so commonly copied, that you can say, it became a meme. It appears there in four answers and answers, and it even got upvotes for barely posting this nonworking piece of code without any additions, which didn't make a good answer, even if it was working. It seems that whenever somebody answers “Clear the console in Java” with this meme, the answer get upvotes immediately because the reader recognizes the meme.

It also re-appears in duplicates, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18224394/2711488) (two times) or [here again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1682212/2711488) (the most upvoted answer) and we’re talking about a six-year-old question.

Comments on the answers telling that it doesn't work are also present for a long time, but they didn't change anything. So here, it’s not about a single incorrect answer, but dozens of them, which have their own life as they can spawn children faster than the voting process (which apparently didn't solve that problem for years) can ever sort them out.

It even goes so deep, that [my added answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33379766/2711488), attempting to clarify the problem and and showing a correct solution got *downvoted*. It seems people don't want to give up the meme. It reminds me of *[The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)* where wrong articles are kept because they make a good read.

So is there an alternative approach to handle wrong answers, when they have a high copying rate or tend to be kept and upvoted, even if they are blatantly wrong?

Comment: Idk, but its definately not a good answer. Maybe the meta effect can get some high rep users to vote to delete or get it down enough for better answers to take precedence.

Comment: @Magisch: if that works, it’s still not a general solution, as we can’t rely on the meta effect for every occurrence of the question. Well, if one gets fixed, we can close the others as duplicates, *in this specific case*, however, I’m still wondering if it wouldn’t be better if there was a kind of “code doesn’t work” flag which allows scheduling to a special review queue, or such alike. Or maybe this case is really exceptional? I don’t know. Urban legends may spread to the same degree, but for easily testable code, it’s strange…

Comment: @holger Removed that comment, it couldn't go anywhere constructive. The only thing I will repeat is that in this case I let the meta effect take its course and I upvoted your answer. I have no clue what can be done in this situation as for me it is already unclear where the real problem begins. The propating of wrong info by rep-whores? Or the fact that wrong information got upvoted so easily (or perhaps: not downvoted?). The only thing I can think of is that there is a lack of verification behind answers - and normally the site doesn't need it because that's what the votes basically do.

Comment: @Gimby: As said, I guess, a lot of developers never have a need for clearing a console so they don’t care, which becomes a problem, when these developers are the ones who answer and vote. Normally, the OP of a question has a strong influence on votes by accepting an answer or leaving comments whether an answer works (at least the OP has an interest in testing the proposals). But in this specific case, the OP seems to have had other serious problems with Java programming in general and was ignored later on and this might have caused ignorance against other comments telling that it doesn’t work…

Comment: Okay but that is maybe true for this one specific example. But this is about the general case isn't it? What to do when broken answers manage to net many upvotes anyway, and to make matters worse based on that pedigree gets copied around a lot. Specifically in the CLS case it is actually quite bad as the only answer you need is actually a link-only answer: a link to "when runtime.exec won't" :)

Comment: @Gimby: Well, what makes it specifically bad and drew my attention to it, is the fact that subsequent newer questions get closed pointing to this question full of unhelpful answers. You’re right, the meta question is about the general case. But identifying the patterns which can lead to such a scenario may help in finding general solutions.

Comment: @Magisch: Even 20Ks cannot delete upvoted answers. That needs a mod with good cause to act.

Comment: @Deduplicator In my knowledge it just needs more delete votes, no?

Comment: @Magisch No, you are thinking of closed questions.

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't think a moderator would remove a highly voted Answer just because its wrong, but a flag could be a shot.

Comment: @Magisch: one former moderator already has removed a highly voted answer—his own…

Comment: Can we say that in certain situations such as this there basically isn't a tangible way of helping a mod to pull the lever with conviction? My brain is meandering towards being able to collect a list of votes from peers to be able to present that in the flag.

Comment: @Holger I'd remove my other answer as well, but it's accepted. :( I've also closed two questions as dupes and applied upvotes/downvotes where appropriate. I think this is all we can do.

Comment: "*Let them eat cake then.*" If people WANT invalid info on the site, how do we fix that? Pull the plug? People get what they deserve.

Comment: @no comprende: what about future readers that are in no way related to the writers and voters of the answers?

Comment: @Holger: if they are more virtuous, I guess they should downvote, etc. If not, not. Wrong info exists. I struggled with a bug for 2 days only to find that there was a line missing from the reference I was using. Oh, well.

Comment: @nocomprende That is a problem that Stack Overflow is trying to fix, not add to.

Comment: @Bill get better members. Are you trying to improve something that the members apparently are not concerned about? Good luck!

Comment: @nocomprende Or, get a better voting system? (OUCH!)

Comment: There is a flag for that, the title is "in need of moderator intervention". By definition anything that the community cannot handle (or has been proven incapable of handling) that is actively harmful to the site is in need of moderator intervention. If the content is actively harmful, does not meet any other flag criteria and can't be dealt with by the community, use a custom flag and explain how the content is harmful and why the community cannot handle it. As always, moderators can disagree with you and decline your flag if they do not find sufficient evidence to validate your claim.

Comment: I see you're trying to have meaningful scores on answers.  You should totally drop that and try jQuery.

Comment: @TinyGiant that's like waiting for a bus that you know it will not arrive, willingly. It is a very screwed logic.

Comment: Holger, the fact that your 'correct' answer has now risen to the top means that SO voting is actually working :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: it’s working in combination with a meta so question, but this can’t be a general solution…

Comment: Should this discussion be used to identify incorrect memes, following the precedent set by @pnuts? I have one in mind that I would dearly like some meta effect applied to.